# Set sslmode=allow with pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, ssl, pg-dump

I need to specify `sslmode=allow` when using psql to connect to my PostgreSQL DB, like: `psql sslmode=allow -h localhost -p 5432`
otherwise I get `server does not support SSL, but SSL was required`

I tried specifying the same option to `pg_dump` but it doesn't recognize the option.

How do I specify `sslmode` to `pg_dump`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to use the environment variable `PGSSLMODE` like this:

`PGSSLMODE=allow pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432`

Comment: Full list of env vars here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-envars.html

Answer (score 0):

see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227805

```
pg_dump "port=<port> host=<host> user=<user> dbname=<db> sslcert=<cert> sslkey=<key> sslrootcert=<ca.crt> sslmode=allow" -f <file>
```

Comment: I believe that requires the postgres server to support ssl

Comment: isn't it a base requirement for any kind of answer to enable ssl in pg_dump to work?

Comment: The premise of the question was about connecting to a server that doesn't support ssl. See my answer for how to do that with pg_dump

Comment: I see what you mean, so I changed my answer to `sslmode=allow`. My point is that there is a way to do it without setting env vars. Am I wrong?

Comment: I see, didn't know that you could put connection options in a string as first arg. So I guess your answer could be simplified to: `pg_dump "port=5432 host=localhost sslmode=allow"`